# Getting A Garbage Value In Bubble Sorting for the Highest Value in C

Tags: c, sorting

I am facing a problem that the Highest value in the array is getting replaced by a random garbage negative value. I am not able to locate the problem. Here is the full source code to the program -

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
int num[10],i,choice,counter=1;
printf("\n\n=====Program To Sort Integer Array=====\n\n");
printf("\nPlease Enter 10 Array Elements = \n");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("\nPlease Enter The %d Element Of The Array\n", i);
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);

}
printf("\n\nHow Would You Like To Sort The Entered Array?\n1. Bubble Sort\n2. Selection Sort\n3. Insertion Sort\n\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);
switch (choice)
{
case 1:{    

           printf("\nYou Have Selected Bubble Sort\n");
           while (counter != 0)
           {
               counter = 0;
               for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               {

                   if (num[i]>num[i + 1])
                   {
                       int temp=0;
                       temp = num[i];
                       num[i] = num[i + 1];
                       num[i + 1] = temp;
                       counter++;
                       break;
                    }
               }
           }
           printf("\n\nThe Array In Ascending Order Is =\n");
           for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               printf("\n%d", num[i]);
           }

           break;
}
default:
    break;
}
_getch();
}
```

The array is getting sorted partially but the highest number is getting replaced. Also, I am using Visual Studio.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: `num[i + 1]` is out of bounds when `i` is `9`, since u loop from 0 to 9

Comment: in gcc, it compiles and runs fine for me

Comment: @SakthiKumar This is the answer but you should form it as an answer for the OP to accept it.

Comment: @AxitSoni - It's not about compiling bro :P

Comment: brooo compile and execute .. both :)

Comment: @AxitSoni - The logic was messed bro :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (num[i]>num[i + 1])
    {
        int temp=0;
        temp = num[i];
        num[i] = num[i + 1];
        num[i + 1] = temp;
        counter++;
        break;
    }
}
```

What happens here when i gets to 9? You compare num[9] and num[10] - the 10th and 11th elements.

I'll assume you already know what happens if you try to access an out-of-bounds array element. If the out-of-bounds value happens to be greater than num[9], you swap it with num[9] - so now the array has a garbage value, and you just overwrote that wasn't part of the array.

Solution: change `i < 10` to `i < 9`. There are only 9 pairs of elements to check (0/1, 1/2, 2/3, ..., 8/9).